# RealityCapture Model Replace Texture

Tags: texturing, uv, texture-painting

I need help at "retexturing" a model, which was made in RealityCapture by photogrammetry and laserscanning. Unfortunetly not every corner was captured good enough, because of display cases so there are textures which i would like paint just white, like the rest of the walls.

The model was unwrapped and textured in RealityCapture.

[image]

I tried to paint the walls white, but after export like to .glb they are blurred. In the view of Blender there are also seams between the UV islands(grey) when I tried to paint the walls white. Is there an other possibility to retexture the model?